# Plotting all observations but colour them based on different group

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2, melt

I have a sample data given below with sample IDs which are unique, and 3 groups. I need to plot all the observations (rows) in 'df' but color them according to the group IDs ('groupid').
Here's what I have so far:

```
# sample data creation
samples <- paste0("S",c(1:9))
groupid <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")
foo <- data.frame(Samples = samples, Group = rep(groupid, each = 3))

bar <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(samples)){
  ran.data <- rnorm(10, 0.5)
  #colnames <- paste0("w",c(1:length(ran.data)))
  for(j in 1:length(ran.data)){
    bar[i,j] <- ran.data[j]
  }
}
df <- cbind(foo, bar)

# ******************
# creating plot data
plotdf <- as.data.frame(t(df))
cols <- as.character(unlist(plotdf[1,]))
plotdf <- plotdf[-c(1,2),] # removing rows
groupid <- df$Group # var to group by
names(plotdf) <- cols
plotdfrows <- names(df[,3:ncol(df)])
plotdf$rownames <- plotdfrows

# melt and plot
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
melteddf <- melt(plotdf, id.var = "rownames")

final.plot <- ggplot(melteddf, aes(rownames, value, colour = variable, group = groupid)) + geom_point() + #geom_line() +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=seq(-3, 3, by = 0.5)) + scale_x_discrete() + 
  labs(title = paste("Sample plot"))  #breaks=seq(0, 4, by = 0.5)

print(final.plot)
```

When I use group = 1, I manage to get the plot but observations are colored differently. But where can I specify the 'groupid' information?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @onlyphantom's answer, there are a few issues with your code.

You have unnecessary manipulation of your `df` to convert to long format. Notice that your original data frame `df` has the column `group` that is lost when you manipulated your data. More so, if you look at the structure of your melted data frame `melteddf`, your code created character values rather than numeric values:

```
str(melteddf)
'data.frame':   90 obs. of  3 variables:
$ rownames: chr  "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
$ variable: Factor w/ 9 levels "S1","S2","S3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ value   : chr  " 0.5705084" " 0.62928774" " 2.2150650" " 0.96091621" ...
```

You need only one line of code to convert to long format, and to preserve your group id's, you can add the `Group` variable to your `id.vars`:

```
melteddf2 <- melt(df, id.vars=c("Samples", "Group"))

str(melteddf2)
'data.frame':   90 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Samples : Factor w/ 9 levels "S1","S2","S3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 ...
$ Group   : Factor w/ 3 levels "group1","group2",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 ...
$ variable: Factor w/ 10 levels "V1","V2","V3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
$ value   : num  0.571 0.611 -0.229 1.378 2.669 ...

head(melteddf2)
Samples  Group variable      value
1      S1 group1       V1  0.5705084
2      S2 group1       V1  0.6106827
3      S3 group1       V1 -0.2288912
4      S4 group2       V1  1.3781335
5      S5 group2       V1  2.6689560
6      S6 group2       V1  1.8686023
```

Finally with respect to your `ggplot2` code, your y-axis values are continuous and you should not use `scale_y_discrete`, while your x-axis is already discrete and `scale_x_discrete` is not necessary. Use `aes(colour=Group)` if you want to use `Group` to define color groups.

```
ggplot(melteddf2, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour = Group)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-3, 3, by = 0.5)) + 
  labs(title = paste("Sample plot"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The value you pass into `aes()` has to be a valid column name from the associated data frame.

This is the data we are going to work with:

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(
  rownames=LETTERS[1:25],
  variables=sample(c("S1", "S2", "S3"), 25, replace = TRUE),
  value=runif(25)
)

groupid = sample(c("group1", "group2", "group3"), 25, replace = TRUE)
# assigning group as a new variable to the data we use for plotting
dat$group <- groupid
```

The data looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   25 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ rownames : Factor w/ 25 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ variables: Factor w/ 3 levels "S1","S2","S3": 3 1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 ...
 $ value    : num  0.2672 0.3861 0.0134 0.3824 0.8697 ...
 $ group    : chr  "group3" "group2" "group3" "group2" ...
```

Notice how the `group` variable is present in the original data. The code for `ggplot` is relatively straightforward:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=rownames, y=value, color=group))+
  geom_point()
```

Produces this:
[image]

The reason your code did not work was that `groupid` wasn't present in the data you pass into the `ggplot` call. You specified `melteddf` as the data parameter, but there was no `groupid` variable in that `melteddf` data frame.

If for some reason you needed the color aesthetics (`col`) to reference values from a different data frame than the one you specified in your `ggplot2` call, you can do that as well.

The following code yield the same result:

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(
  rownames=LETTERS[1:25],
  variables=sample(c("S1", "S2", "S3"), 25, replace = TRUE),
  value=runif(25)
)
# group is a different data frame from dat
group = data.frame("groupid"=sample(c("group1", "group2", "group3"), 25, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=rownames, y=value))+
  geom_point(aes(col=group$groupid))
```